# execute query in field table with postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Can we execute a query stored in data table with PostgreSQL?

For example I have a table:

[image]

And with the result I expected by executing the following query:

```
select * from table where sla_id = 1001
```

[image]

Note: today's date is `2022-06-14`.

Comment: [minimal reproducible example](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The link is about asking on dba.stackexchange.

Comment: Canonical link: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Store the deadline_time as an interval and you can do the calculation:
SELECT CURRENT_DATE + deadline_time AS output FROM table WHERE sla_id = 1001;